# i'm unable to compile a simple C function program in Dev c++?

Tags: c, dev-c++

I'm trying to compile in Dev-C++,
program is:

```
main( )
{
    message( ) ;
    printf ( "\nCry, and you stop the monotony!" ) ;
}

message( )
{
    printf ( "\nSmile, and the world smiles with you..." ) ;
}
```

Errors are:

```
E:\Dev\fn.cpp [Error] 'message' was not declared in this scope
E:\Dev\fn.cpp [Error] ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'message' with no type [-fpermissive]
```

Edit: Silly mistake. Was compiling a `c` program as `cpp`

Comment: Are you writing code with c and compiling it as c++?

Comment: This is not valid C, nor C++, so no wonder. I believe that book has a bad reputation for teaching old, outdated stuff.

Comment: If it is a C book, you should try compiling with a C compiler. Also, the book looks like it could be pre-C89 standard. Many C compilers will barf a that code.

Comment: Please bear in mind that C and C++ are two completely different languages, and that the book you are using is of negative value, so throwing it away amounts to profit.

Comment: @juanchopanza This is standard C89 (if the appropriate header was included). Which compilers barf at that code please? I don't know a single one.

Comment: @FUZxxl My bad. I thought implicit function declarations were out in C89, but I guess it is C99. So why would the header be needed?

Comment: @juanchopanza You need to declare functions with variable argument lists before you call them. That's an exception to the rule that you don't need to declare a function before calling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, compile your C code as C code, not C++ code. The extension of C code should be `.c`, not `.cpp`.

Then, recognize that there may be wrong things in books and correct code.
You shouldn't omit types of return value and arguments, and functions used should be declared before it is used.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h> /* declaration of printf() will be here */

/* bring this function before using */
void message(void)
{
    printf ( "\nSmile, and the world smiles with you..." ) ;
}

int main(void)
{
    message( ) ;
    printf ( "\nCry, and you stop the monotony!" ) ;
    return 0;
}
```